# Is an electric circuit patentable?

Tags: patentability, engineering

If I make an electric circuit for a specific purpose would it be patentable?

The circuit is not complicated, it is simple for a very simple task.

Comment: Is the circuit novel?  Is the circuit non-obvious to someone skilled in the arts?  Is their prior art where someone else has created that circuit?

Comment: Darlington transistor is a simple, intuitive, and useful circuit, and it was patented: https://www.google.com/patents/US2663806

Comment: The Darlington transistor may not have been so intuitive in 1952.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing particular about electrical circuits that make them unpatentable.  Your circuit, if useful, novel, and non-obvious, is likely patentable.  If it is a simple thing for a simple task, then it may have already been disclosed by another in which case it would not be novel and therefor not patentable.  If the circuit is an obvious variation of something that has been done before, then it may also be rejected.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, definitely. There are many, many circuits that are patented.